# Access Token contains almost all information from Identity Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, access-token, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

The tokens below are returned upon initial token request with *Azure AD B2C*. `access_token` contains most information that `id_token` contains.

My **questions** are that:

1 Since `access_token` contains most information that id_token contains, what scenario can `access_token` be used in place of `id_token`? what scenario must `id_token` be used instead of `access_token`?

2 What are the rules regarding use of both `access_token` and `id_token` in general?

**Result upon initial token request**

```
{
"access_token": "access_token",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": "3600",
"refresh_token": "refresh_token",
"id_token": "id_token"
}
```

Below is the decoded token for the respective token:

Please note that `access_token` contains most information from `id_token`, including user information.

**access_token**

```
{
"iss": "url",
"exp": 1550539339,
"nbf": 1550535739,
"aud": "audience ",
"idp": "LocalAccount",
"sub": "guid",
"name": "user@email.com",
"emails": [
"user@email.com"
],
"tfp": "B2C_1_ROPC_Auth",
"ver": "1.0",
"iat": 1550535739,
"azp": "guid"
}
```

**id_token**

```
{
"iss": "url",
"exp": 1550539339,
"nbf": 1550535739,
"aud": "audience ",
"idp": "LocalAccount",
"sub": "guid",
"name": "user@email.com",
"emails": [
"user@email.com"
],
"tfp": "B2C_1_ROPC_Auth",
"ver": "1.0",
"iat": 1550535739,
"auth_time": 1550535739,
"at_hash": "access_token hash"
}
```

**Update**

Further to question 1 above:
Since `access_token` contains most information that `id_token` contains, can `access_token` be used instead of `id_token`? That is, when `id_token` must be used instead of `access_token`?

Answer (score 0):

I will take google as a example,

1) let say you want to implement `social login` where u mostly need fields like `email`, 'first_name', 'last_name'., these fields are mostly available in `id_token`. so `id_token` is perfect suitable for `authentication`.

2) later u need to fetch `google contacts` of the login user., In such scenarios u can't get `contacts` of the user in `id_token`. this is where `access_token` comes, though u won't have the `contacts` in access_token but all permission to fetch the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

An ID token is intended for authentication. It is represented as a JSON Web Token (JWT) that contains claims about an authentication event including the identity information for a resource owner. The ID token is intended for a client application (a single-page app) and its `aud` (audience) claim contains the OAuth 2.0 `client_id` of the client application.

An access token is intended for access by clients to resources that are owned by a resource owner. It is represented as either a JWT (e.g. Azure AD B2C represents an access token as a JWT) or an opaque token. The access token is intended for a resource application (e.g. an API app) and its `aud` claim contains the OAuth 2.0 `client_id` of the resource application.

Comment: "An ID token is intended for authentication." For ROP, I cannot see ID token is used. But access token is used for revocation endpoint, introspection endpoint, etc. One Azure B2C, audience claim is the same on both ID token, and access token.Can you please links on what you said, because I cannot understand the last bit related to use of aud on each of both paragraphs (e.g client app and resource app).

Comment: Hi @Pingpong. The ROPC flow issues an ID token so that the client application can identify the authenticated user. One of the important protections for tokens is they must only be valid for use with a specific application (i.e. the intended "audience") and with a specific scope. The `aud` claim specifies this intended application. For an ID token, it's set to the `client_id` of the client app; for an access token, it's set to the `client_id` of the resource app. In case of the ROPC flow, if the token request contains an API `scope`, then an access token is issued for use with the API app.

Comment: Hi @Pingpong. Did the above answer and explanation help you?

Comment: Our clients are PDA devices, what are the best audience setting on both ID token and Access token via ROPC?